# How to delay the camera function that uses zxing library?

Tags: ios, zxing

I use zxing to scan barcodes. But the camera scans real quick ,so that my method gets overloaded with the result. How to slow down it or create a delay to scan the barcodes?

Here is my result method:

```
- (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result {


if (!result) return;


// We got a result. Display information about the result onscreen.
NSString *formatString = [self barcodeFormatToString:result.barcodeFormat];
NSString *display = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Scanned!\n\nFormat: %@\n\nContents:\n%@", formatString, result.text];



        [self.decodedLabel performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setText:) withObject:display waitUntilDone:YES];

// Vibrate

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);



  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use sleep function. Try to use  sleep(timeInSeconds) ,so it will delay the scanner by the seconds you enter.

Answer (score 2):

You could record an `NSTimeInterval` and reject all results for the next 'x' seconds. Example of detecting at most once every half second:

```
- (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result {
  if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] < _nextUpdateTime) {
    return;
  }
  _nextUpdateTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] + 0.5;
  // remainder of function.
}
```